# Simulating Stochastic Matrix Differential Equation with Arbitrary Autocorrelation Function

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, stochastic-calculus, random-process

I want to numerically simulate a matrix differential equation that includes a stochastic (vector) Gaussian noise $\mathbf{n}$, where the different vector components are independent, and each component has an arbitrary autocorrelation function $R_i(\tau)$, so:

$$\mathbb{E} [n_i(t) n_j(t+\tau )] \equiv R_i(\tau) \ \delta_{ij}$$

(Let's say the process is zero mean). As a minimal example, consider the following matrix DE:

$$\dot{X}(t) = \Big({F_0}(t)+{n_1}(t) A + n_2(t) B \Big) X(t) $$
$$X(0) = \mathrm{id}_{2\times 2}$$

with

$$F_0(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin(t) & t \\
0 & e^{-t}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

And let's say that I want the noise autocorrelation function to be:
$$R_j(\tau) = e^{-j \tau^2} \qquad j \in \{1,2 \}$$

I looked at the documentation and I couldn't really find anything I could use to generate a continuous-time process with an arbitrary autocorrelation (I thought about using [TransformedProcess](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedProcess.html) for instance, but I couldn't figure out how exactly it can be done). Most other stochastic DEs solved in other questions are also done with more standard processes such as the Wiener process (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30558/solving-a-stochastic-differential-equation) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148072/how-to-solve-a-stochastic-differential-equation) answer). What would be an efficient way of simulating such systems where the noise has some non-standard spectral density?